# Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_result kernel 4.4.169

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, openwrt, kbuild

I am trying to build kernel module [rtl8192eu](https://github.com/Grief/rtl8192eu) for Turris Omnia router using openwrt crosscompile toolchain. Everything looks fine except that the module cannot be inserted if I set `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211`. I need that option, otherwise I am not able to control the wifi dongle. But the module itself loads and recognizes the dongle without that flag enabled.

If the flag `CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211` is enabled, `insmod` fails with

```
8192eu: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)  
8192eu: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_result
```

However as far as I can see, `cfg80211` exports 'mirrored' symbols:

```
➜  cat /proc/kallsyms|grep -E 'ieee80211_get_channel|cfg80211_connect_result'
bf6bea08 T ieee80211_get_channel        [cfg80211]
bf6e1010 t __cfg80211_connect_result    [cfg80211]
```

Since the module compiles and works on my PC from the same sources without an issue and exported symbols on PC are matching to the above 'mirrored' ones, I guess I do compile the module for router incorrectly. Maybe some linkage issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't got a warning at building stage about those symbols? Normally, situations "unknown symbol" are detected at build stage.

Comment: @Tsyvarev not at all. I see all cfg80211 symbols as unresolved at compile stage. However only those two are not there in cfg80211. Anyway, I fixed this issue. But the driver still doesn't work.